# Express.js modules & Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: express, parse-platform, quickblox

I'm using Parse.com and express.js. I'm new to webdev and Parse.com is making things complicated.

I want to use an external SDK - QuickBlox. Here's the structure of the SDK:

[image]

When I take `quickblox.js` and include it in a `<script>` tag, and then call `QB.init()` then the SKD works fine.

However, I want to put all this functionality in one of my routes. Problem is, I can't `npm install` since I'm using Parse's cloud server.

So I copied `quickblox.js` into a cloud folder and am trying to load it as a module like so:

```
var QB = require('cloud/libs/quickblox.js');
```

I did the same thing with `async.js` and it worked. However, it's not working for Quickblox. When I call `QB.init()` now I get:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'init'
```

Thing is, I'm new to this environment so I can't tell if this is something fundamental I'm doing wrong or it's something particular the situation.

---

EDIT

I looked into `quickblox.js` and found these possibly relevant lines:

```
// Creating a window scoped QB instance
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.QB === 'undefined') {
  window.QB = new QuickBlox();
}
```

and

```
// Browserify exports
module.exports = (typeof window === 'undefined') ? new QuickBlox() : QuickBlox;
```

So, since I'm not running this client-side then there is no `window` object and `window.QB = new QuickBlox();` never gets run, right? And this is the only reference to the `QB` in the .js file.

And since `(typeof window === 'undefined')` should be true, then `module.exports` is getting set to `new QuickBlox()`... but what object do I reference to get to `init()`?

Here is where `init()` is defined:

```
  // Actual QuickBlox API starts here
  function QuickBlox() {}

  QuickBlox.prototype.init = function(appId, authKey, authSecret, debug) {
  this.service = new Proxy();
  this.auth = new Auth(this.service);
  this.users = new Users(this.service);
  this.content = new Content(this.service);
  this.location = new Location(this.service);
  this.messages = new Messages(this.service);
  this.data = new Data(this.service);

  // Initialization by outside token
  if (typeof appId === 'string' && !authKey && !authSecret) {
    this.service.setSession({ token: appId });
    appId = '';
  }

  config.creds.appId = appId;
  config.creds.authKey = authKey;
  config.creds.authSecret = authSecret;
  if (debug) {
    config.debug = debug;
    console.log('QuickBlox.init', this);
  }
};
```

[And the actual `quickblox.js` file on github.](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/blob/master/quickblox.js)

Comment: you must learn how to add quickblox server side library i have same problem too. and try to find way.

Comment: you can do this with quickblox api . but in that situation you need add some client api request .

Answer (score 1):

From a brief look at the QuickBlox github, it would seem you would put the contents of the "js" folder either in your "cloud" folder or a "QuickBlox" sub-folder, you wouldn't use the browserified version unless you wanted to access QuickBlox from the client browser.

Assuming you put everything in the "js" folder inside a sub-folder called "QuickBlox" you would then reference it in your Cloud Functions by adding a `requires(..)` statement, e.g.

```
var QB = requires('QuickBlox/quickblox');
```

This will load all the modules and attach them to the QB variable too, so in your Cloud Functions you can then do things like (pulled from the sample on their site):

```
QB.init(appId, authKey, authSecret);

// create an API session (user is not authenticated)
QB.createSession(function(err, result) {
  if (err) { 
    console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log('Session created with id ' + result.id);
  }
});

// list the users currently enrolled
QB.users.listUsers(function(err, result) {
  for (var i=0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
    console.log('User ' + result.items[i].login + ' is registered');
  }
});
```

Comment: it is not work because this kind of library work client side not server side